# WPF C# lock/unlock button and execute a thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, button

Can somebody help me understand why this piece of code don't work?

What I want to do is : Click the button, change the button content and lock it, execute a external thread and finally, unlock the button and change the content again

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button3.Content = "Printing...";
    button3.IsEnabled = false;

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    button3.IsEnabled = true;
    button3.Content = "Print";
}
```

Comment: Known problem.  You need to use the dispatcher to get the user surface synched up to your contents.

Comment: @daveL, buttons do not have a Text property

Comment: Calling Thread.Sleep in a UI event handler blocks the UI thread. Search StackOverflow for "UI freezes" or "block UI thread" or similar to get answers in abundance.

Comment: @user2941172 - You can refresh GUI before sleeping on thread by invoking empty delegate on dispatcher with priority set to `Render`. Added more details in my answer with downsides of using that approach.

Comment: As a simple rule of thumb you should *never* call Thread.Sleep in the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens - Completely agree over this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is because your method (which handles the button's `Click` event) is running on the same thread as the UI. This concept is a common source of problems when working with UI code.

Put simply, the UI cannot be re-drawn until your method has completed. During the method you disable your button, wait for 1 second, then re-enable the button - and *then* the UI is redrawn, with the button enabled. For this reason, you never see the button disabled on-screen (and your application will be freezing up for 1 second while the `Sleep` happens).

What you need to do instead is investigate one of the methods available for running a task on a background thread. Your method should create and start this thread, set the button to disabled, and then complete - allowing the UI thread to draw the button as disabled. When your task is complete you should set the button to enabled again (note that typically in WPF this will mean using `Dispatcher.Invoke` to ensure that `button.Enabled` is set from the UI thread).

To create your background task, you could look at the `System.Threading` namepaces (specifically the [`Thread.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.start.aspx) method), or the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), or the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. I suspect the TPL will be your easiest starting point.

Comment: Most of it right. But this line - `the UI cannot be re-drawn until your method has completed` is not true always. If i enqueue task with priority `Render` on UI dispatcher, UI will refresh before method completion. Check out the details in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are `sleeping on UI thread` which freezes your UI thread and hence you are not seeing any update on UI.

> Redrawing of controls is done by UI dispatcher but dispatcher performs
>   the operation based on priority set for the task. Redrawing of
>   controls are done on dispatcher priority set to Render. Setting
>   content of button is queued on dispatcher with priority render but it
>   will get execute only once all tasks with higher priority gets
>   completed.

As other's have suggested you should move your long running task on separate thread but there's another workaroud to refresh GUI before sleeping on UI thread. Like i mentioned UI will be redrawn once all tasks higher than `DispatcherPriority.Render` gets completed. So, what you can do is `before sleeping on thread enqueue an empty delegate with render priority synchronously` which will `force dispatcher to perform all tasks above and with priority render` before moving to next task. This is what i meant -

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button3.Content = "Printing...";
    button3.IsEnabled = false;

    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render); <-- HERE
    // button3.Refresh(); <-- After having extension method on UIElement.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    button3.IsEnabled = true;
    button3.Content = "Print";
}
```

Also you can have this method as extension method on UIElement -

```
public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
{
    uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
}
```

And call simply `button3.Refresh()` before sleeping on UI thread.

> But, this has a downside too since it won't only refresh your button3
>   but all other controls which are pending for refresh on UI because dispatcher will complete all
>   tasks with priority render or higher before moving to next task.

**But keep in mind always, never sleep on UI thread.**

Comment: Technically this will work, but it's working by yielding to *everything else on the dispatcher queue* with a priority above `Render`. That's a pretty non-deterministic sledgehammer to crack a nut - and it's not the most obvious or readable code, either. You're right in that there is almost always *some way* to change the usual behaviour, but I'd never advocate this. If I saw this code in a code review, I'd reject it.

Comment: @Dan - That's also i don't encourage either that's why mentioned a downside of using this approach at last. I agree with all you mentioned in the answer, posted it since it is one of approaches to refresh UI (definitely not encouraging) :)

Answer (score 0):

Making the handler asynchronous takes care of the problem:

```
private async void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button3.Content = "Printing...";
    button3.IsEnabled = false;

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    button3.IsEnabled = true;
    button3.Content = "Print";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you are disabling the button when it is clicked but not enabling again. what can you do is,

```
1. initiate a timer

when button is clicked then,
1. change content, disable the button
2. start the timer
3. after a certain duration when the external thread is executed enable the button again and change it's content.
```

Hope this helps
Thanks.

Comment: The line "button3.IsEnabled = true;" in the posted code would suggest that your answer not right...

Comment: yeah you are right, but i only mentioned another way. that's it.